# MIPS SPIM-CACHE simulator lw exception

Tags: arrays, compare, 2d, mips

So i have to write for an assignement for my university a code in MIPS which will compare A[i][j] with B[i][j](A and B are 4x4 arrays),and will place the biggest number in A[i][j] and the smallest in B[i][j]. This is the code i have already wrote:

```
.data
Ann: .word 4, 6, 10, 5, 4, 7, 10, 8, 3, 6 ,7, 12, 3, 2, 15, 6
Ban: .word 3, 7, 5, 6, 5, 12, 18, 9, 7, 6, 12, 4, 2, 7, 8, 4


.text            
.globl main      

main:   la    $t0, Ann       # $t0 represents start address of A[i][j]
la    $t1, Ban           # $t1 represents start address of B[i][j]
lw    $s2,0($t0)
lw    $s1,0($t1)                         

addi   $s5, $zero, 4    # set maximum iteration to be 4 
addi   $s6, $zero, 0     # set i = 0

loopi:  addi   $s7, $zero, 0     # set j = 0
jal    loopj             # starts inner loopj
addi   $s6, $s6, 1       # i++
bne    $s5, $s6, loopi   # continue loopi if i < 4
j      finish            

loopj:  sll    $t7, $s6, 2       
add    $t7, $t7, $s7
sll    $t7, $t7, 2       # 4 * ((i * 4) + j)  
add    $t9, $t7, $s2     # address of A[i][j]
lw     $t6, 0($t9)       # value of A[i][j]
add    $t4, $t7, $s1     # address of B[i][j]
lw     $t5, 0($t4)       # value of B[i][j]


slt $t8,$t6,$t5         
beqz $t8,cont
add $t2,$zero,$t6
add $t6,$zero,$t5
add $t5,$zero,$t2
sw $t6,0($t4)
sw $t5,0($t9)        
cont:   addi   $s7, $s7, 1       # j++
bne    $s5, $s7, loopj   # continue loopj if j < 4
jr $ra







 finish: li  $v0, 1           
    add $a0,$s5, $zero 
    syscall
```

When i try to run it to spim cache,i get an exception at the instruction "lw     $t6, 0($t9)       # value of A[i][j]" .... What could be wrong,i have no idea :\

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you learn how to use the debugging features that simulators like SPIM and MARS provide, because finding the cause of errors like these is quite easy.

If you just try to run the program normally you'll get a bunch of execptions, and the first one occurs at PC=0x400064, which is at `lw $t6, 0($t9)`.

So you set a breakpoint at 0x400064, and when the breakpoint is hit you inspect the register values to see if they look reasonable. Well, `$t9` contains the value 4, which is not a reasonable address to try to read from.

You got the value for `$t9` by adding `$t7` and `$s2`, so the next thing to do is look at those two registers. `$t7` has the value 0, which seems ok since we're on the very first iteration, where `i` and `j` are both 0. `$s2` has the value 4, which seems wrong, because I'm going to assume that this is supposed to be the base address of the array.

And how did you end up with `$s2=4`? By doing `lw $s2,0($t0)` which loads the first value in the `Ann` array into `$s2`. And that's your problem.